# Biztalk LAST_UPDATE_DATE,UPDATEDUSER,CREATEDUSER,CREATION_DATE

Tags: biztalk

I have to create one interface read CSV file and send the request to SQL system to insert data.

In the schema generated for SQL request have createdate field which have datatype as datetime and Nillable as true.

Issue is when I receive the file with empty value for this field getting below error

> The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value.    at
>   System.Xml.Schema.XsdDateTime..ctor(String text, XsdDateTimeFlags
>   kinds)

I tried defult value NULL (In DB if I use insert into using sql query table allows NULL value) But when i set Null value in the request sent by biztalk its not.
"

> The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port 
>   "SQLPORTNAME" with URL "SQLSERVERCONNECTIONDETAILS". It will be
>   retransmitted  after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. 
>   Details:"Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.XmlReaderParsingException:
>   The input data for the field/parameter "CreatedDate" is invalid
>   according to the expected SqlDbType DateTime. --->
>   System.FormatException: The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value.
>   at System.Xml.Schema.XsdDateTime..ctor(String text, XsdDateTimeFlags
>   kinds)    at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String s,
>   XmlDateTimeSerializationMode dateTimeOption)    at
>   Microsoft.Adapters.Sql.MetadataHelper.ConvertXmlValueToDotNetObject(String
>   xmlString, String fieldParameterName, SqlDbType sqlDbType, Int32
>   maxLength, Int32 precision)    --- End of inner exception stack trace---
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action,
>   Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) "

Expected result - request should go to SQL without any issue for null/empty values

Answer (score 0):

Change the schema datetime field to a string (nullable) type. This makes parsing easier and less restrictive.

The downside is the loss of automatic conversion of datetime values to the current culture, but I will leave that to you if it's really a downside.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . But sql schema(input to the destination sys) i can not change to string .....So datetime datatype in the sql schema not accepting the null/empty value.

Comment: @bigB you don't have to change the SQL tables or procedures or anything like that, just modify the XSD. It works even if it's not really a string in your SQL Server.

Comment: I generated schema using the sql connection that schema I can't change....Input flatfile schema the field is datetime (this i can updat as tring) destination sql schema its date time(This i m not able to update) when this sql request sending to table opertion this error occurs for empty values